# To be easy of vs. the easiness of

Tags: grammar

This is the sentence I would like to review:

> The reason for that is **easy of** programmability for emerging platform.

Sounds wrong to me since I believe "a Noun" of "another Noun" is more grammatically correct. Thus, it should be:

> The reason for that is **the easiness of** programmability for emerging platform.

Which one is correct, if either?

Comment: @Hank I think It must be "a Noun" of "another Noun" ?

Comment: What are your thoughts of *"The reason for that is **the ease of** programmability for emerging platform."*

Comment: That may be OK, but I also want to know if these former are correct or not.

Comment: I would say the **easy of** usage is incorrect while the **easiness of** usage is correct, but highly not recommended.

Comment: Easiness is wrong here. And your sentence is not great. But then, this is editing and we don't do that here, supposedly.

Comment: @Lambie: could you elaborate ? why `easiness` is wrong ?

Comment: It's wrong, because in English easiness is the state or condition of being easy. The programming cannot be said to have that state or condition. Whereas, ease is the effort you make in doing something. For example: /The ease with which that player beat all the other players was astounding./ Notice: /ease of programming as regards emerging platforms/ ease: for the programmer. Ease means it doesn't cause major problems for someone; easy means not difficult. You can do something very difficult with ease, but that does not mean it is "easy".

Answer (score 1):

**Ease** is more commonly used than "easiness".

> "The reason for this is **the ease** of programmability for emerging platforms"